# Automatically updated calendar using formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have a table with information about various events (1 row = 1 event). One of the columns in the table holds the date of the event in the format "YYYY-MM-DD".

The calendar in which I am trying to make the events appear automatically have one cell with information about year and month in the form "YYYY-MM-01". The day of the month is held in a seperate cell in the calendar on the format "D"/"DD".

If the year, month and day match, I want the acronym (held in a column in the table of events) of the event to be returned by the function and displayed in the calendar.

My first thought was to use a function like this:

`=IF(AND(YEAR(Table13[Start Date])=YEAR($A$1);MONTH(Table13[StartDate])=MONTH($A$1);DAY(Table13[StartDate])=DAY(F3));Table13[Acronym];" ")`

but I realised looking thru the table like that wont work.

Any ideas on how I can proceed? I hope the explanation isnt too messy.

[Link to example file](http://freakshare.com/files/urrtz70k/Example.xlsm.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your start of month and day numbers are stored as values, not text, then use this:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A$1+F3-1,Table13!$A:$C,3,0),"")
```

Where Table13 is the worksheet where the lookup is happening with the data stored in columns A:C.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(VALUE($A$1)+VALUE(F3)-1,Table13!$A:$C,3,0),"")
```

Would work if the dates are text.